# DTOs Collections mapping Problem

Tags: orm, architecture, dto

I'm working now on a multi-tier project using .Net which has layers as following :

- DAL
- BLL
- GUI Layer

and Shared DTOs between BLL and GUI layers.

I'm facing a problem in mapping the Objects from **DAO To DTO**, No problem in 
the simple objects.

The problem is in the Objects who have child collections of another objects.
ex:

```
Author                      Category
--Categories                --Authors
```

**the execution goes in an infinite loop of mapping**

and it get more complex when I want model Self-join tables
ex:

```
Safe                                    Safe
--TransferSafe(Collection<Safe>)        --TransferSafe(Collection<Safe>)
```

**the execution goes in an infinite loop of mapping**

any suggestions about a good solution or a practical mapping pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're using, but if you're in .NET you can use the very handy [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).  It makes these sorts of things a ton less manual, and helps solve your infinite loop problem.

Comment: I've tried Automapper and I've got the same result ... and at the end I got a 'System.StackOverflowException', any help !!

Comment: What do your mappings look like?  You should use the examples on the automapper site to see how to tell it to intelligently handle things